# How would I pass this parameter back if it has a period in it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The controller does not accept periods passed back to it. So how would I pass back the parameter `required_doc.completion_status` ?

```
<a ng-class="completion_status(required_doc.completion_status)">
    {{required_doc.completion_status}}% Complete
</a>
```

```js
$scope.completionClass = function(required_doc.completion_status) {
    if(required_doc.completion_status == 100)
        return "success"
    else
        return "failure";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not put a dot inside the function's parameter name:

```js
$scope.completionClass = function(status) {
    if(status == 100)
        return "success"
    else
        return "failure";
};
```